# Why would an event be null? (object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: c#, events, delegates, null, invoke

I have a form with a button, a label and a progress bar, so that when I click the button it creates an instance of class b to run a process. Once the process is done it will call an EventHandler to show "done" in the main form's label!

I created an event (SetStatusEvent) of a delegate (SetStatus) to do this. And it seems fine when I call this event outside the EventHandler (usbforProcessExited) but when I call it from usbforProcessExited it gives an error -

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

**main form**

```
public partial class main : Form
{
    b rsSet = new b();

    public main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rsSet.SetStatusEvent += new RemoteS.SetStatus(updateStatus);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rsSet.FormatUSB();
    }

    private delegate void UpdateStatus(int i, string str, Color clr);

    private void SetStatus(int i, string str, Color clr)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Value = i;
        this.lbl_status.ForeColor = clr;
        this.lbl_status.Text = str;
    }

    private void updateStatus(int i, String msg, Color color)
    {
        object[] p = GetInokerPara(i, msg, color);
        BeginInvoke(new UpdateStatus(SetStatus), p);
    }

    private object[] GetInokerPara(int progress, string msg, Color color)
    {
        object[] para = new object[3];
        para[0] = progress;
        para[1] = msg;
        para[2] = color;

        return para;
    }
}
```

**class b**

```
class b
{
    public delegate void SetStatus(int i, string msg, Color color);
    public event SetStatus SetStatusEvent;

    System.Diagnostics.Process usbfor = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    public void FormatUSB()
    {

        usbfor.StartInfo.FileName = @"usbformat.bat";
        usbfor.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        usbfor.Exited += new EventHandler(usbforProcessExited);
        usbfor.Start();
    }

    public void usbforProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs f)
    {
        SetStatusEvent(100, "DONE", Color.Green); //ERROR HERE! (object reference not set to an instance of an object
    }
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You should learn to produce minimal working examples. Your code contains lots of stuff that's not relevant to this question.

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of your problem, but don't you need "usbfor.EnableRaisingEvents = true" for the process to raise the Exited event?

Comment: @ChrisSpicer OPS! actually I do have that line! I was just trying to minimize the amount of code I post. Thanks for mentioning that part.

Comment: You could consider replacing your `b` class and its events by a `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a race condition:

`usbforProcessExited` gets subscribed in the constructor of `b` and might be invoked before you called `rsSet.SetStatusEvent += new RemoteS.SetStatus(updateStatus)`.

You should only call `usbfor.Start()` after you subscribed to `SetStatusEvent`.

A related problem is that the event will run on another thread. You should set `rsSet.SynchronizingObject` before starting the process so your event handler can modify the form without manually calling `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`.

Answer (score 11):

The event is null, if there are no subscribers.

There are two solutions:

1. Initialize the event when declaring (dummy subscriber doing nothing):

   ```
   public event SetStatus SetStatusEvent = delegate { };
   ```
2. Check the event for null before raising (in a thread-safe way):

   ```
   public void usbforProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs f)
   {
       SetStatus setStatus = SetStatusEvent;
       if (setStatus != null)
       {
           setStatus(100, "DONE", Color.Green);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The null check (even when done correctly) leads to a lost event in the OPs code. So it's not the solution here.

Comment: The null check would in this case only hide the symptom.

Comment: @daygoor You should still use this pattern when writing your Raise event methods. As you say in your own words (which is interesting since you are the OP), "when done correctly".

Answer (score 3):

Jon Skeet has taught me that in c# 6.0 you can also use:

```
SetStatusEvent?.Invoke(100, "DONE", Color.Green);;
```

Answer (score 1):

The event is `null`, if noone subscribed to it yet. 
So it's a good practice to control on `null` equality, like:

```
    public void usbforProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs f)
    {
        if(SetStatusEvent!=null)
            SetStatusEvent(100, "DONE", Color.Green);
    }
```

That's why *outside* it works well, as you have, this line:

```
 rsSet.SetStatusEvent += new RemoteS.SetStatus(updateStatus);
```

so subscription and initilizaton of the event.

When you call it from *inside*, there is no any subscription made, so event is `null`.

*EDIT*

Following the comments let's provide more thread safe approach of handling null reference check on event:

```
   public void usbforProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs f)
    {
        var ev = SetStatusEvent; //[1]
        if(ev!=null) //[2]
            ev(100, "DONE", Color.Green);
    }
```

Remember that assignment operation ia atomic in CLR, so even in between lines [1] and [2] someone else reset event to null, your `ev` will be still valid and code will execute without crashing. IF this is desired behaviour or not it depends on *your concrete case*, so this is just another option to manage null reference control on event in thread-safe way.

Comment: Except that's not thread-safe - if the last subscriber unsubscribes between the check and the call, you'll end up with a NullReferenceException. That may or may not be a problem, depending on what threading you want to support.

Comment: I normally do `var handler = SetStatusEvent;` first (although I cannot find the reference for why)

Comment: The null check (even when done correctly) leads to a lost event in the OPs code. So it's not the solution here.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: he talks about "inside" and "outside", I believe he means calling that function from the "b" class and from "main" form respectively. Don't think there is any raise condition involvedhere, but simple wrong understanding of events intialization-

Comment: @CodesInChaos Even though it might not fix the current problem, it should still be coded correctly.